# inner join symfony doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Currently I have this DQL query which I want to rewrite with a QueryBuilder, but because I play several entities it is complicated, I have seen examples but I do not understand how more than one entity is related to the code I want to rewrite is the following:

```
Public function getDepartamentoEmpresaEmpleado($numdoc){
    // Muestra todos los departamentos de la empresa a la cual pertenece el empleado logeado
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $empresa_repo = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Empresa');
    $idempresa = $empresa_repo->getVerIdempresa($numdoc);
    $dql = "SELECT a FROM BackendBundle:DepartamentoRrhh a 
                INNER JOIN BackendBundle:CentroCosto        b WITH a.idcentroCosto      = b.idcentroCosto
                INNER JOIN BackendBundle:Empresa            c WITH b.idempresa          = c.idempresa
                WHERE c.idempresa = :idempresa";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('idempresa', $idempresa);
    $Departamentos = $query->getResult();
    return $Departamentos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$Departamentos = $empresa_repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
->innerJoin('a.idcentroCosto', 'b')
->innerJoin('b.idempresa', 'c')
->andWhere('c.idempresa = :idempresa')
->setParameter('idempresa', $idempresa)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

There is no need to specify Entity when doing innerJoin because
doctrine already knows about it through the entity mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this in the repository of DepartamentoRrhh entity

```
public function getDepartamentoEmpresaEmpleado($numdoc){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $idempresa = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Empresa')->getVerIdempresa($numdoc);

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->innerJoin('a.idcentroCosto', 'b')
        ->innerJoin('b.idempresa', 'c')
        ->where('c.idempresa = :idempresa')
        ->setParameter('idempresa', $idempresa)
        ->getQuery();

    $Departamentos = $query->getResult();
    return $Departamentos;
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you very much